# I am making a 2d platformer and this code lets the player jump infinitely fixes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code most of it is other movement options but the jumping is the main problem when the player presses space he jumps infinitely please help.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float runSpeed= 2;
    public float jumpSpeed= 3;
    Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    public bool betterJump = false;
    public float fallMultipliplier =  0.5f;
    public float lowJumpMultiplier = 1f;
    
    void Start()
    {
       rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(runSpeed,rb2D.velocity.y);
        }        
        else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(-runSpeed,rb2D.velocity.y);
        }  
        else
        {
            rb2D.velocity=new Vector2(0,rb2D.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("space") && CheckGround.isGrounded)
        {
            rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(rb2D.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code for `CheckGround`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckGround : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool isGrounded;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    private void OnTiggerExit2D(Collider collision)
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for looking at my question!

Comment: Wait, you never reduce `rb2D.velocity.y`, this is why once you jump, you go up forever. Seems like you have no gravity

Comment: So either what I wrote above regarding lack of gravity, or what I initially wrote with `CheckGround.isGrounded` maybe always returning `true`

Comment: ok the check ground code is this using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckGround : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public static bool isGrounded;


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    private void OnTiggerExit2D(Collider collision)
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }

}

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't your `OnTiggerExit2D` be `OnTriggerExit2D` (typo)

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional trigger-only object to detect whether your character is on a floor or not.
That means add another game object as a child of your character, give it a box collider 2d and place it just a bit below the characters feet, outside of the main collider. With this placement, it's ensured that other solid objects like walls and ceilings, never hit it, because the whole character will be stopped due to its main collider.
Then add a script to that child-object which handles the collisions and sets an "is_grounded" boolean to the main character controler.

Furthermore you should read about "layers": https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html
By placing for example your jump-handler collider on another layer and your enemies on a third layer, you can prevent that the character can jump off enemies heads by disabling collissions between those two new layers (while maintaining that the character itself can still collide with the enemies to take damage etc.)

Comment: Is there any simpler fixes i can use i am very new to unity i i am not shure i can remodel my code in such a complicated way